# Kaitai Struct dump to json

Tags: json, kaitai-struct

I need a command line like "ksc" which can take parameters "binary file" and "yaml file" and dump it in json format.
WebIDE is doing the same through "ExportToJson", but i need the same functionality from command line.

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

Affiliate disclaimer: I'm a [Kaitai Struct](https://kaitai.io/) maintainer (see my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/generalmimon)).

> I need a command line like "ksc" which can take parameters "binary file" and "yaml file" and dump it in json format.

Use the utility [`ksdump`](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_visualizer/blob/master/bin/ksdump) included in the [kaitai-struct-visualizer](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_visualizer) package. You can get it [from RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/kaitai-struct-visualizer) by running `gem install kaitai-struct-visualizer` (this will make the command `ksdump` available on your `PATH`). You need to have Ruby installed, though. Also `kaitai-struct-compiler` is required to be installed (see https://kaitai.io/#download for instructions) and set up on your `PATH`.

The usage for your case is the following:

```sh
$ ksdump -f json sample.bin protocol.ksy
```

Alternatively, instead of installing Ruby, Kaitai Struct compiler and visualizer manually, you can pull the official Docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/kaitai/ksv, which comes with everything included. The usage looks like this (naturally, you need to [get Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) in the first place):

```sh
$ docker run -v "$(pwd):/share" --entrypoint ksdump -it kaitai/ksv -f json sample.bin protocol.ksy
```

But consider that the Docker image [`kaitai/ksv`](https://hub.docker.com/r/kaitai/ksv) takes up 1.06GB (I didn't expect that - I guess it's quite easy to get Docker images bloated), so you might not want to download it all through a slow network or a connection with data limit.

Comment: Kaitai structure visualizer and ksdump do not support Opaque types, Is that right?
https://doc.kaitai.io/user_guide.html#opaque-types